# Same function exported by two dlls, which one is called?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

Function `void foo()` is exported by two dlls, D1 and D2.
Main program links to both D1 and D2 and calls foo.

```
void foo();
int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

This compiles and links successfully in visual studio. When I run the program, I notice D1's version of foo is called.

Shouldn't visual studio have given a linker error since it found two matches for foo? In the Main program's Configuration Properties -> Linker -> CommandLine, I notice it has D1.lib before D2.lib. Is this the reason why D1's version of foo got linked to Main (whichever comes first on the command line get linked deterministically)?

Comment: Duplicate symbols in .lib files are not a problem to the linker.  It simply picks the first one it sees.  You cannot call both unless you use LoadLibrary + GetProcAddress.

Comment: Seems right. If the linker processes arguments from left to right, I guess the first one it sees is the first one on the command line then.

Answer (score 1):

For calling a function in a `.dll` or `.lib` you need to include a header file with the function definitions.

In your case you definitively include only one of the two headers, or write the function prototype in the cpp directly. If you would included both header the compiler give you error of ambiguous call.

If you only include one of the two header and the compiler known with certainty what function to call (for example with some `#pragma comment(lib...)` the compiler would call the expected function.

If there is no indication of the `.dll` or `.lib` the header file refer to the compiler would call the first one processed.